# Formula is changed when Google form update sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I have created a Google Form. Data submitted through this form is automatically saved to an associated worksheet named "Answers". In the same document, I created a new sheet named "Presentation" for data presentation.
Data from "Answers" is imported 1: 1 using reference =(Answers!A1)
When a new entry is added from the form, it correctly appears at the end of the list on "Answers". Unfortunately, at the same time, the addressing in the "Presentation" spreadsheet changes by itself, as if the row had been deleted or something.

More details:

Content of 5 rows and 3 columns in "Presentation" looks like:

```
1   =(Answers!A2)   =(Answers!B2)
2   =(Answers!A3)   =(Answers!B3)
3   =(Answers!A4)   =(Answers!B4)
4   =(Answers!A5)   =(Answers!B5)
5   =(Answers!A6)   =(Answers!B6)
```

When the third form is sent addressing in "Presentation" is changing by itself and looks like this:

```
1   =(Answers!A2)   =(Answers!B2)
2   =(Answers!A3)   =(Answers!B3)
3   =(Answers!A5)   =(Answers!B5)
4   =(Answers!A6)   =(Answers!B6)
5   =(Answers!A7)   =(Answers!B7)
```

Then of course I can't see the value on line 3 of "Answers". If I send another form, it is like this:

```
1   =(Answers!A2)   =(Answers!B2)
2   =(Answers!A3)   =(Answers!B3)
3   =(Answers!A6)   =(Answers!B6)
4   =(Answers!A7)   =(Answers!B7)
5   =(Answers!A8)   =(Answers!B8)
```

I have no idea where the error is or why it is. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrayformula in Presentation's tab. Put in row#1

```
={"title of column";arrayformula(Answers!A2:A)}
```